# solving algorithm bug when list item appears more than one time in text

Tags: python, python-2.7

This function has to detect the negation words in text and add NEG_ prefix to the word after negation word. the logic is to save the index of negation word in text list, then add the NEG_prefix to (index+1)

The problem is that, when the text has for example more that one "not", it is not working correctly.

```
def negationDetection(tweet):
position = []
words = tweet.split()
#to prevent error when negation word appears at the end of text
size = len(words)-1 
print words
negationList = ["not","no","never"]
for word in words:
    if word in negationList:
        if words.index(word) != size:
            position.append(words.index(word) + 1)
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
print position
for i in position:
    tweet = (tweet).replace(words[i], 'NEG_' + words[i])
return tweet
a = "hello I am not good,but I can never feel it"
print negationDetection(a)
```

The result is

> hello I am not NEG_good,but I can never NEG_feel it

It is correct, but when the text is "**hello I am not good,but I can not feel it**", the result is

> hello I am not NEG_NEG_good,but I can not feel it

instead of

> hello I am not NEG_good,but I can not NEG_feel it

How can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bug is in:

```
position.append(words.index(word) + 1)
```

You get the position of word, in this case 'not', using `index`. This always returns the first occurrence of the word. An easier way is to iterate over index rather then iterate over word.

```
negationList = ["not","no","never"]
for word in range(len(words)):
    if words[word] in negationList:
        if word != size:
            position.append(word + 1)
        else:
            continue
    else:
        continue
```